# python elasticsearch use transport client

Tags: python, elasticsearch, client, transport

I am newbie to elasticsearch, I know there is two official client  elasticsearch supplies, but when I use the python elasticsearch, i can't find how to use the transport client..
I read the whole doc which is as following:

```
https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html
```

I also search some docs, i can't find the way to use elasticsearch with python.also, in one doc, it says:

> Using the native protocol from anything other than Java is not
>   recommended, as it would entail implementing a lot of custom
>   serialization.

does this mean python elasticsearch can't use transport client?

Answer (score 3):

The transport client is written in Java, so the only way to use it from Python is by switching to Jython.

Comment: So no way to run it with python script?

Answer (score 1):

I think the previous answer is out of date now, if this is [the transport client you mean](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/transports.html).

I've made use of this API to do things like use the [_rank_eval](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.7/search-rank-eval.html) API, which is still considered "experimental" so hasn't made it into the official client yet.

```
def rank_eval(self, query, ratings, metric_name):
    res = self.es.transport.perform_request(
        "GET",
        "/%s/_rank_eval" % INDEX,
        body=self.rank_request(query, ratings, metric_name),
    )
    return res
```